# flask sqlalchemy : sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am new developer, i try to create small app in flask - sqlalchemy and flask_admin.
This is my models :

```
class Language(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "languages"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(length=50), nullable=False)

class Article(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'articles'
    from_language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('languages.id'), nullable=True)
    to_language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('languages.id'), nullable=True)
    language_from = db.relationship('Language', backref='article_language_from')
    language_to = db.relationship('Language', backref='article_language_to')
```

models get me this error :

> sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join
> condition between parent/child tables on relationship
> Article.language_from - there are multiple foreign key paths linking
> the tables. Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of
> those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key
> reference to the parent table.

i want to use model Language in model Article 2 times, from_language_id and to_language_id,
How i can solve my error ?

EDIT: my mistake, the error is comming from flask_admin ==> https://pastebin.com/R2E2zp18 , how i can fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Language(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "languages"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(length=50), nullable=False)

class Article(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'articles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    from_language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('languages.id'), nullable=True)
    to_language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('languages.id'), nullable=True)
    language_from = db.relationship('Language', backref='article_language_from')
    language_to = db.relationship('Language', backref='article_language_to')
```

Output:

```
test=# \d articles
                                 Table "public.articles"
      Column      |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |               Default                
------------------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------
 id               | integer |           | not null | nextval('articles_id_seq'::regclass)
 from_language_id | integer |           |          | 
 to_language_id   | integer |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "articles_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "articles_from_language_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (from_language_id) REFERENCES languages(id)
    "articles_to_language_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (to_language_id) REFERENCES languages(id)

test=# \d languages;
                                   Table "public.languages"
 Column |         Type          | Collation | Nullable |                Default                
--------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------
 id     | integer               |           | not null | nextval('languages_id_seq'::regclass)
 name   | character varying(50) |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "languages_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "articles" CONSTRAINT "articles_from_language_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (from_language_id) REFERENCES languages(id)
    TABLE "articles" CONSTRAINT "articles_to_language_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (to_language_id) REFERENCES languages(id)
```

Comment: my mistake, the error is comming from flask_admin ==> https://pastebin.com/R2E2zp18

Comment: If you do not specify the primary key field in Article class then it will give you the error. So you just need to specify that...

Error:

raise sa_exc.ArgumentError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper mapped class Article->articles could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'articles'

Comment: How i can do that ?

Comment: I've done all the things. You have to use my above suggestion code

Answer (score -1):

Hi so i just copied your code and added id in `Article` class and it works [here](https://repl.it/repls/RemoteTimelyCommand#main.py) take a look

Comment: my mistake, the error is comming from flask_admin ==> https://pastebin.com/R2E2zp18